# Why my UICollectionView doesn't scroll to the last item of my list?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UICollectionView with a horizontal scroll that shows 3 cells for each page but when I get to the last page there is only one element and it does not let me scroll to show this last element.

This is my list:

```
var benefitIcons = ["ic_benefit_frappe", "ic_benefit_birthday", "ic_benefit_2x1", "ic_benefit_points", "ic_benefit_combo", "ic_benefit_cine", "ic_benefit_tickets", "ic_benefit_refill", "ic_benefit_klic", "ic_benefit_pay"]
```

This is the method for UICollectionView:

```
extension ProfileCCViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return benefitIcons.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = benefitCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BenefitCell", for: indexPath) as? UserBenefitsCell {
        cell.benefitIcon.image = UIImage(named: benefitIcons[indexPath.row])
        cell.benefitLbl.text = benefitDescriptions[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    } else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/3, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    benefitControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let width = scrollView.frame.width
    let horizontalCenter = width / 2
    
    benefitControl.currentPage = Int(offSet + horizontalCenter) / Int(width)
}
```

}

This how look like correctly:

[image]
But when I'm scrolling to the last item and is uneven doesn't scroll to this last section:

[image]

Comment: How did you add the collection view to you VC? what is the scrollView doing here?

Comment: @SimeonRumy it's added with the array of icons that is in assets and the scroll it's by default from the component in horizontal mode but the last item of this scroll it's not showing and I don't know why the collection view have this behavior :(

Comment: I am suspecting it might be a auto layout constraints issue. Maybe add your code showing how collection view is constrained or did you use storyboard?

Comment: @SimeonRumy Yep I can add the storyboard and the constraints used in this component

Comment: Yes, I cant spot anything wrong with the current code you have posted. It should scroll till the end unless there is something else thats miss configured.

Comment: Do you happen to have any updates on this? I have a similar issue

Comment: @narek.sv yep the solution was to add some configuration for collection view, this are the changes for scroll to the last position without any problem [this is the configuration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rVLsDtYe2E53PQ-j7QDHFvR21h6-ZbLX/view?usp=sharing) the trick it's in min spacing for cells and for lines, I hope my research helps you to resolve your issue